# Rails: Acts As Votable won't allow other users to vote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm able to vote, but it's not letting new users vote the same thing? Users can vote things that doesn't have votes on them already, and once they do vote it, another user won't let them.

I have setup CanCan, and I noticed its giving me the same error as if I'm not able to access certain things. So, I'm assuming it has to do with some authentication? Not letting other users to vote? Am I wrong for having `:upvote` and `:unvote` in my `before_action`?

Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :unvote]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :upvote, :unvote]


  def upvote
    @project.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def unvote
    @project.unliked_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  ... #more codes here...

end
```

View

```
- unless (current_user.voted_for? @project) && (@project.liked_by current_user)
  = link_to like_project_path(@project), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
      = @project.get_likes.size        
- else 
  = link_to unvote_project_path(@project), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
      = @project.get_likes.size
```

Comment: If you are to uncomment `load_and_authorize_resource` does it allow you to upvote and downvote?

Comment: @coletrain it seems like that was it... but why is that? Don't I need that for my other authenticate uses though?

Comment: you will need to specify in your ability.rb file `can :manage, Project, :user_id => user.id`. In your controller try `load_and_authorize_resource :user` let me know if this works

Comment: @coletrain that works still. Thanks! Not sure what would break if I added `:user` thought. So far, it seems fine.